# Timer not running normally - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am sorry for asking this question. I am relatively new to Javascript. I got help in building a countdown timer but suddenly it runs in twos. What could I be doing wrong? I think I am missing one tiny detail but I just can't find it. What could be wrong please.

```js
    $("#coinbtn1").click(function() {
      var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
        display = document.querySelector('#time1');
      startTimer1(fiveMinutes, display);
    });
    
    function startTimer1(duration, display) {
      var timer = duration,
        minutes, seconds;
        
      var intervalFn = function() {
       
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
    
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    
        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
     
     if(--timer != 0){
      document.getElementById('coinbtn1').disabled = true;
     }
     
     if (--timer === 0) {
        clearInterval(myVar);
        document.getElementById('coinbtn1').disabled = false;
      }
        
      };
      
      myVar = setInterval(intervalFn, 1000);
      
      intervalFn();
      

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
          <div>Timer : <span  id="time1">05:00</span></div>
                                <div class="mdl-grid">
           
           <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
           
                                    <button id="coinbtn1" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored">
           50 coins 
           </button>
           <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
                                </div>
           
                            </div>
```

Please help.

Comment: You are decrementing `timer` twice per run through intervalFn: (`--timer` subtracts one from timer) - change the second condition to read: `if (timer === 0) {`

Comment: Ohhhhh dammit! I knew it! Thanks a lot. I am so ashamed right now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have two `if` statements that use `--timer` in their conditions.

`--timer` will cause `timer` to decrease regardless of the whether the `if` condition is `true` or not (`--` is the ["decrement" operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Decrement_(--))).

Instead, just check `timer-1` (which doesn't cause `timer` to be modified) and then manually decrease the timer just once after both those tests.

```js
$("#coinbtn1").click(function() {
  var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
  display = document.querySelector('#time1');
  startTimer1(fiveMinutes, display);
});
    
function startTimer1(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
  var intervalFn = function() {
       
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
    
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    
    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
     
    // Don't decrease the timer in the test
    if(timer-1 != 0){
      document.getElementById('coinbtn1').disabled = true;
    }
     
    // Don't decrease the timer in the test      
    if (timer-1 === 0) {
      clearInterval(myVar);
      document.getElementById('coinbtn1').disabled = false;
    }
  
    --timer; // Decrease the counter just once.
  }
 
  myVar = setInterval(intervalFn, 900);
      
  intervalFn();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
  <div>Timer : <span  id="time1">05:00</span></div>
  <div class="mdl-grid">      
    <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>     
    <button id="coinbtn1" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored">50 coins</button>
    <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As someone with high rep, I'd expect you might satisfy this in a simple comment, rather than go for the reputation with a full answer on something that's basically a typo...

Comment: @cale_b I guess you can chalk it up to you and I having different ideas of what a "typo" is.

Comment: @cale_b, I think you're both right.. it depends on how you look at it. In one way it seems that the OP lacks basic understanding of prefix arithmetic operators and on the other hand it might be just a simple "--" more added in the code, funnny. :)

Answer (score -1):

You are decrementing `timer` 2 times in

```
if(--timer != 0){
        document.getElementById('coinbtn1').disabled = true;
}

if (--timer === 0) {
      clearInterval(myVar);
      document.getElementById('coinbtn1').disabled = false;
}
```

Use if-else instead of `if` two times and decrement timer once at the end. Like this.

```
if(timer != 0){
    document.getElementById('coinbtn1').disabled = true;
}
else if (timer === 0) {
      clearInterval(myVar);
      document.getElementById('coinbtn1').disabled = false;
}
timer -= 1;
```